# What does this line mean in rfc2068

Tags: http, rfc, http-1.0

[source](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt)

> In addition, the proliferation of incompletely-implemented
>   applications calling themselves "HTTP/1.0" has necessitated a
>   protocol version change in order for two communicating applications
>   to determine each other's true capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the RFC:

> HTTP has been in use by the World-Wide Web global information initiative since 1990. The first version of HTTP, referred to as HTTP/0.9, was a simple protocol for raw data transfer across the Internet.

Rephrased:

Before HTTP was standardised there were differences in implementations that meant they couldn't always communicate with each other correctly (e.g. certain web-browsers couldn't work with certain web-servers). The RFC article refers to these pre-standardisation implementations as using `HTTP/0.9`.

> HTTP/1.0, as defined by RFC 1945, improved the protocol by allowing messages to be in the format of MIME-like messages, containing metainformation about the data transferred and modifiers on the request/response semantics. However, HTTP/1.0 does not sufficiently take into consideration the effects of hierarchical proxies, caching, the need for persistent connections, and virtual hosts. In addition, the proliferation of incompletely-implemented applications calling themselves "HTTP/1.0" has necessitated a protocol version change in order for two communicating applications to determine each other's true capabilities.

Rephrased:

After HTTP was standardised as `HTTP/1.0` it certainly helped the interopability and compatibility problems, but version `1.0` of the protocol simply assumed all HTTP software would be able to use it for their existing application, but now that `HTTP/1.0` has been in-use for a while the maintainers of the HTTP protocol specification saw that **they need to extend HTTP to support these use-cases** (e.g. proxies, caches, persistent connections, virtual-hosts) and while these things could be done using the built-in extension mechanisms in `HTTP/1.0` they felt a need to increment the version number to `HTTP/1.1` in order to prevent an implementation simply assuming the remote host supports a feature or not.

### Example

A good example is the `Host` header in `HTTP/1.1` that allows for a web-server serving from a single IP address and port number to serve-up different websites based on the `Host` header (as before `HTTP/1.1` existed webservers could only serve one website per IP address, which is a problem). `HTTP/1.0` does allow clients and servers to add their own custom headers, such as `Host`, however there is no way for the client or the server to know that the other end actually supports the `Host` header. But in `HTTP/1.1` the `Host` header was formerly added to the specification so if both the client and server declare they use `HTTP/1.1` then the other end knows that they'll recognize the `Host` header and handle it correctly.

So in the `HTTP/1.0` days, **with custom headers**, this is how it would play out if a browser requests `www.example.com` if it were served from a Shared Webhost:

```
Browser (to DNS server): "Please give me the IP address for 'www.example.com'"
DNS Server (to browser): "www.example.com is 198.51.100.7"

Browser (to 198.51.100.7): "Hello, I speak HTTP/1.0, please send me index.html for Host: www.example.com
Server (to browser): "I also speak HTTP/1.0, here is index.html for 'not-actually-example.com'"
```

As you can see, the browser got `not-actually-example.com` even though it asked for `www.example.com`, because the Web-server was using `HTTP/1.0` which does not recognize the `Host` header, even though the web-browser was sending the `Host` header (as an extension/experimental header). **The browser software has no way of knowing if `not-actually-example.com` is what the user wanted or not**.

Answer (score 1):

In human terms, what they're saying is: so many people said they did HTTP 1.0 while they didn't, that nobody knew whether it really was HTTP 1.0 any more when someone said it.

To get out of that, they chose a new number.